# "Take offense" usage

Tags: prepositions

What prepositions do I use with "take offense"?

Specifically:

"I take offense *at* you *over* your words"

Are *at* and *over* correct?

Comment: You take offense at *something*, not its agent (person causing it). "I take offense at your words" should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

> I take offence at your choice of words

Or

> Your choice of words offend me

- added value is to not attack the person but what he/she is saying

Answer (score 1):

While "take offence at" is used more frequently, "take offense with" is also correct and sounds more "natural" to me in some cases. Consider

"I took offence at the way that she spoke to me" versus

"I took offence with her for the way that she spoke to me."